# Didn't understand what this code does

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel.I am confused what this code actually does.I was surfing through this [link](http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-52-crud-create-read-update-delete-example-from-scratch).The part of the code are from step 3:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $products= Product::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('ProductCRUD.index',compact('products'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Since you've changed the **whole** question.
That code will get the top 5 of all products, ordered by the id of products in descending order. Then the products data are passed into the view named **index.blade.php** inside **ProductCRUD** directory. You could find that directory on yourproject/resources/views.

It also flashes a session variable named i (on the view you could access the variable using $i), which have the value of the **form input / query string** named **page**, if it exists. Otherwise, the **$request->input('page', 1) = 1**.

From the usage of that variable, the **$i** will act as starting row number of each page on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

- This method is called when your route is "productCRUD"
- ProductCRUD UI called with the product data

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Select query is fired on a table named product by using its model i.e. Product with order by id DESC
        $products= Product::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);

        // view is returned with some data and the value passed in the query string is used here
        return view('ProductCRUD.index',compact('products'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```